# Content of meta tag not get fetched by Crawler

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am working on a Wordpress plugin to post WordPress post on Fb as an SWF video.

I was able to post to FB and worked perfectly before 14-05-15. But Now when I make a post, it is only posting the link of the page*.

When I debug it with https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug it is showing a critical error

> "Error parsing input url,No data was cached or no data was scrapped".

On clicking "**Fetch New Scrape Information**" it is showing two critical Errors.

> "Error parsing input url, No data was cached or no data was scrapped"*

and

> CURL Error:RECV_ERROR receieved HTTP code 502 from proxy after connect*

Again When I click "**Fetch New Scrape Information**" All the meta tags get fetched and showing my Post.

When I Refresh Share attachment,It will displayed perfectly. But I needed to show this from the first time when I post from WP.

```
    <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $data['title'];  ?>" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $data['descripton']; ?>" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $data["preview_img"]; ?>" />
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="300" /> 
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php echo $data['title'];  ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:video" content="<?php echo WPFBAP_SWF.'fbap.swf?wpContent='.urlencode($data["content"]).'&bg_clr='.$data["bg_color"].'&bg_image='.$data["bg_image"].'&font_color='.$data["font_color"].'&repeat='.$data["image_fill"].'&video_url='.$data["video_id"]; ?>" />
    <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    <meta property="og:video:width" content="400">
    <meta property="og:video:height" content="360">
```

These are the meta tags I am using. What is Wrong ?

Comment: Are you using any caching plugins in your wordpress? a cached version of your page might be served to the facebook crawler and it could be the issue. Moreover, it always recommended that you pre-fetch your content the minute they become available as mentioned [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#precaching)

Comment: @ifaour No it is currently fetching.It was reported as a bug in Fb and it is now fixed. [Bug Report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1475437416081617/)